# Setting Build Automatically in Eclipse via configuration file

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any way by which we can set "Build Automatically" option to true via a configuration file so that this option would be checked as soon as eclipse gets started. This is just because the workspace is made ready with the help of a batch file which compiles the code and then opens the eclipse also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default settings is **true**, anyway if you want to force this behavior you need the following line `description.autobuilding=true` in the `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` file.

This preference file is located under the `.metadata` folder of the workspace, ie:

`C:\Workspaces\MyWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs`

Answer (score 0):

With Eclipise Mars.1 (4.5.1), you may be able to use Oomph's setup feature.

On Windows, files under
%USERPOFILE%.eclipse\org.eclipse.oomph.*

permit putting Eclipse into a desired state the next time Eclipse starts up.

I indirectly became aware of Oomph's power after troubleshooting a "problem" with Build Automatically getting mysteriously disabled.

After posting on the Oomph Eclipse Community Forum, I learned that Oomph has been disabling Build Automatically.

Some ways to see Oomph's settings "Eclipse->Navigate Menu-> Open 
Setup menu entry-> Open User menu entry", a Preference Task under "User Preferences -> org.eclipse.core.resources -> description.autobuilding"

For more info, see the discussion post at
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1722751/#msg_1722751